# Error Origin URI when Uber API with Javascript

Tags: cross-domain, uber-api

I'm developing an web application using uber API and I got some problems when I send request to uber API:

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Origin '...... our origin https url' is therefore not allowed access."

I set Origin URL (which is https link) in our app board and using below code to refresh token key:

```
parameters = {
    'redirect_uri': 'my redirect link',
    'refresh_token': "my refresh token",
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'client_secret': 'my secret client',
    'client_id': 'my client ID'
};
var data = new FormData();
for (var item in parameters) {
    data.append(item, parameters[item]);
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/token', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log("access_token: " + data.access_token);
    var refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
    console.log("refresh_token: " + refresh_token);
};
xhr.send(data);
```

And one more information, that code running well before and error above just happen some days ago.
If you need details about my app board information please let me know.
Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Please edit your comment to include the code of the full request and response details.

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/api-reference#cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing - Are you testing locally? If so you need to add all of the urls/domains as origins in the developer dashboard.

Comment: Sorry for lately reply. We completed testing in local. And we test in our server link. We added urls/dommain as origins in the account developer dashboard but it still error.

Comment: and one more information, our origin url is https://bundleweb.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/